# Control or manipulate Fire transparency effects?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, procedural, emission, fire

I copied [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvbphr8EUYQ).

My blend file:
[image]

Now, how do I control the fire transparency? Like these:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @L0Lock thanks, it worked

Comment: Glad it helped! Please upvote and mark the answer as valid via the checkmark icon in the top left corner of the answer ;)

Comment: @L0Lock as effective as your answer is, hope I can find more alternatives as well

Comment: What for would you need alternatives?

Comment: Besides curiosity, (parts of) the alternatives may be applicable to other procedural effects or geometry nodes as well. Or just to better understand procedural effects

Comment: But this is applicable to anything that can have a shader. Alternatives could be to use compositing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your Emission node and material output, add a Mix Shader node. Plug the Emission output to the first Mix's shader input, and add a Transparent BSDF node plugged in the Mix's second input.

You can play with the Mix's factor value to change how much you mix the Emission with the Transparent BSDF shader. 0 is fully Emission shader, 1 is fully Transparent BSDF shader.

[image]